Windows 10 system partition disappear, can't boot Windows 10
I use Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 10 dual-boot with a GRUB bootloader, and after using Windows 10, a BSOD happened [unknown error]:

After this error, I did a hard poweroff via the power button while Microsoft tried to get 'some data' (I needed to go)

Now I see that there are no partitions on this disk [/dev/sda], and GRUB can't do anything with it [Windows 10's system disk]

I cant read/write to it or create new GPT partitions via fdisk:
fdisk: failed to write disklabel: Input/output error


testdisk:
read/write error every cilinder




What can I do?


SMART data & self-test:  

lsblk: sda    disk 223.6G SATAFIRM S11



sudo lshw -class disk:

  *-disk:0                  
     description: ATA Disk,
     product: SATAFIRM   S11,
     physical id: 0,
     bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,
     logical name: /dev/sda,
     version: 61W5,
     serial: TPBF2209020010200871,
     size: 223GiB (240GB),
     configuration: ansiversion=5, logicalsectorsize=512 ,sectorsize=512




From your description, the drive might be dead. Test it. If it is working, then either restore from last drive image, best, or reinstall first Windows, then Linux (losing all data and starting from scratch).

@JoepvanSteen, SSD. I add addition in question

For S.M.A.R.T data, please don't post GUI screenshots, instead please copy/paste the output of  smartctl -a /dev/sda into a code box, as it has info not shown via GUI apps.This is also the only way to determine whether the drive has hardware damage. Once you obtain the S.M.A.R.T data, run a long S.M.A.R.T test via smartctl -t long /dev/sda, updating the S.M.A.R.T data in the code box once the test has finished (~3hrs/TB)
